# Where are plug-ins supposed to be added in ServiceStack

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

So simple yet I can't find any info or examples that explain exacty where this should happen. I'm guessing at this point that it should be in the Configure method.

Thank you,
Stephen

**Global**

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost() : base("Web Services", typeof(ContactsService).Assembly) { }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        //Set JSON web services to return idiomatic JSON camelCase properties
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;

        //Show StackTrace in Web Service Exceptions
        SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = true });


        //Register any dependencies you want injected into your services
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

/*            // Redis
        container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => new PooledRedisClientManager());
        container.Register<IRepository>(c => new Repository(c.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>()));*/


        container.Register<IRepository>(new Repository());
        container.Register<IBusinessService>(new BusinessService());

        //Configure Custom User Defined REST Paths for your services
        /*ConfigureServiceRoutes();*/

        //Add a request filter to check if the user has a session initialized
        /*this.RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) =>
        {
            var sessionId = httpReq.GetCookieValue("user-session");
            if (sessionId == null)
            {
                httpResp.ReturnAuthRequired();
            }
        });*/


        RequestFilters.Add((httpReq, httpResp, requestDto) => new LogRequestAttribute().Execute(httpReq, httpResp, requestDto));

        Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
    }

    public static void Start()
    {
        new AppHost().Init();
    }
}
```

**Updated**

```
public AppHost() : base("Web Services", typeof(ContactsService).Assembly) { }

public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    ....

    ConfigurePlugins();
}

private void ConfigurePlugins()
{
    Plugins.Add(new ProtoBufFormat());
    Plugins.Add(new RequestLogsFeature());
    Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
}

private void ConfigureServiceRoutes()
{

}

public static void Start()
{
    new AppHost().Init();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no info because [Plugins](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins) in [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) can be added **anywhere** inside your `AppHost.Configure()` method. This is true of all ServiceStack configuration and registration of dependencies, services, filters, etc.

It doesn't matter where in the `AppHost.Configure()` method they're added because they're only **Initialized** by ServiceStack after it has been called.

They are however initialized (i.e. `IPlugin.Register()` is called) in the same order that they were added.

Comment: OK, I just added them all to a ConfigurePlugins method.. for lack of a better name.